# oAuth using Google API creating Hybrid App

Tags: javascript, android, html, authentication, oauth

I am trying to create a login page using google oAuth.
For this i have created a  clientID.
In ClientID i have done created for Android since i believe i app would be running on an Android Device.

**Create Client Id ->Installed Application -> Android**

I have done keytooling and signed it with SHA1 and create a clientID

then i created a **Public API Access**. In this i have created an **Android Key**. I have provided the com name and SHA1 details. Since i am using an **INTEL XDK** it was easy to get the COM namespane from there.

In my javascript code i have done something like this to construct the URL.

> var clientID ="client_id=";  var responeType =
>   "&response_type=code";  var scope ="&scope=profile";  var scope
>   ="&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly";  var redirectURL ="&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";  var url
>   ="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?"+clientID+responeType+scope+redirectURL+"&approval_prompt=auto";

then i have used an XHRRequest to give a call to this URL

> var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();   xhr.open("GET",url,false);
>   xhr.onload = function()   {
>         if(xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200)
>         {
>            console.log(this.response); 
>             var resp = this.response;
>
> ```
>   }   }     xhr.onerror = function(e)   {
> alert("Error : "+e)   }   xhr.send();
> ```

I have a button with event listener attached to it.
I am new to android and especially to oAuth. I am getting all sort of errors such
as

Please copy this code, switch to your application and paste it there:

when i click the button i do not see any login Page from google asking for permission
but i can see data coming in console.log().

What is wrong that i am doing here.

If there are any way to create Hybrid APp using html5 please share.
also please tell me if i am doing it write or wrong.Please guide me.

-S

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `jQuery` plugin for Oauth2: https://github.com/krisrak/jquery-cordova-oauth2

It works with [Intel XDK](http://xdk.intel.com)

All you have to do is modify the call below with your Oauth Client parameters and the callback will have access_token to start making calls

```
$.oauth2({
    auth_url: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
    response_type: 'code',
    token_url: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
    logout_url: 'https://accounts.google.com/logout',
    client_id: 'CLIENT-ID-FROM-GOOGLE',
    client_secret: 'CLIENT-SECRET-FROM-GOOGLE',
    redirect_uri: 'http://www.yourwebsite.com/oauth2callback',
    other_params: {scope:'profile'}
}, function(token, response){
    makeAPICalls(token);
}, function(error, response){
    alert(error);
});
```